# Wording a regex with bash find and boolean match

Tags: regex, bash

I'm not at all sure why this doesn't work. Other posts here suggest that it should. I just want a regex on find to locate all files that match ***_*__orig.png** and ***_*__DIFF.png**. This will find the first:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*_____orig\.png'
```

But this finds nothing:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*_____(orig|DIFF)\.png'
```

What is the correct way to phrase the regex to match both? (Yes I know I can use -or to have a much longer and less maintainable comamnd...)

Comment: You have a different number of underscores in the boldface example file names (3) and your regex (5). Why is that?

Comment: There are actually many more underscores... doesn't matter how many I match. I just want to locate those files so that they can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape both parens and the pipe, use:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*_____\(orig\|DIFF\)\.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU find's -regex uses emacs flavour by default, which I'm not very familiar with.  You can change the regex used with -regextype. With `-regextype posix-extended` your current -regex should work.

The portable way is to use two -name operators.

```
find . -type f \( -name "*_____orig.png" -o -name "*_____DIFF.png" \) -print
```

Or, with bash 4.0 or newer, you can use globstar and extglob instead of find

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
for file in ./**/*_____@(orig|DIFF).png; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! It did not actually work for the find in my system (OSX Lion) but it identified the flag -E which caused my regex to work properly.

Comment: find -E . -type f -regex ".*_____(orig|DIFF)\.png"

Comment: @AliceYoung, Ah, I thought only GNU find had `-regex`, so I assumed you were using GNU find.